# Cannot find symbol error _ PrintWriter.printf() method _

Tags: java

I am trying to write formatted text into a file with a `PrintWriter.printf()`.

When compiling on **ubuntu(Java version is 1.6.0_41)** I get the error :

```
cannot find symbol method printf(java.lang.String, int)
```

I tried with the method `printWriter.format ()` but gives the same error.

On **Windows(where Java version is 1.8.0_162)** it works.

Here's the method containing the error:

```
public void fileWriting(TestSerialMsg message) throws IOException {

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("ReceivedMsg.txt");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    printWriter.print("Some String");
    printWriter.printf("received counter is %d",message.get_counter());
    printWriter.close();
   }
```

The error :

```
TestSerial.java:85: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : method printf(java.lang.String,int)
 location: class java.io.PrintWriter  
     printWriter.printf("received counter is %d",message.get_counter());  
                ^  
 1 error
```

Comment: What is TestSerialMsg class?

Comment: Can you show us the Java version you attempt to compile with?

Comment: This method was added in Java 5, so please check Java version.

Comment: the java version is  "1.6.0_41" . And when I check the PrintWriter class declaration with ' javap' the printf(java.lang.String, Object..) is well defined

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for method [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is an array of `Object`. The value returned by your method `message.get_counter()` is an `int` which is a primitive and not an `Object`. Hence the message that there is no `printf` method that takes two parameters where the first is a `String` and the second is an `int`.

Create an `Integer` from the value returned by `message.get_counter()` and use that as the second argument when you call method `printf`, i.e.

```java
printWriter.printf("received counter is %d", Integer.valueOf(message.get_counter()));
```

Alternatively, you could use method `println` instead of `printf`, as in...

```java
printWriter.println("received counter is " + String.valueOf(message.get_counter()));
```

Comment: The 2nd suggestion doesn't return an error indeed, but it's not printing into the file.  The 1st returns the same error ,just that this time the not found method is  `printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)`.  Also,as I said, the code worked when I tried on windows (the java version is 1.8.0).   furthermore, the method `java.io.PrintStream printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`  which has the same signature as `PrintWriter.printf` has never returned an error when an `int` is passed as argument.